# A sufficient condition for convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ $(n \geq 1)$ and $X$ be real-valued random variables defined on the same probability space. If every subsequence of $X_n$ contains a further subsequence that converges to $X$ almost surely, then $X_n\overset{P}{\rightarrow}X$.

Disclaimer: This is not an exercise. It is a exam preparation question that I was not able to solve.

Comment: Three questions, three disclaimers!

Answer (score 2):

In my answer I will give a proof of:

> $X_{n}\stackrel{P}{\to}X$ if every subsequence $\left(X_{n_{k}}\right)$
>   of $\left(X_{n}\right)$ contains a further subsequence $\left(X_{n_{k_{i}}}\right)$
>   with $X_{n_{k_{i}}}\stackrel{P}{\to}X$.

This is a stronger statement because $X_{n_{k_{i}}}\stackrel{\text{a.s}}{\to}X$ implies $X_{n_{k_{i}}}\stackrel{P}{\to}X$.

If $X_{n}\stackrel{P}{\to}X$ is not true then some $\epsilon>0$
exists such that $P\left(\left|X_{n}-X\right|\geq\epsilon\right)$
will not converge to $0$.

That implies the existence of a $\delta>0$
together with a subsequence $\left(X_{n_{k}}\right)$ such that $P\left(\left|X_{n_{k}}-X\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\geq\delta$
for each $k$.

For every further subsequence $\left(X_{n_{k_{i}}}\right)$
we also have $P\left(\left|X_{n_{k_{i}}}-X\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\geq\delta$
for each $i$.

Consequently $X_{n_{k_{i}}}$ will not converge to $X$ in
probability.

Proved is now the existence of a subsequence $(X_{n_k})$ that has no further subsequences that converge to $X$ in probability.